# Proof of a premise to easily prove Cantor-Bernstein-Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don‘t know the name of the theorem, but it makes it pretty easy to prove CB-Theorem.

It goes like this: If N, M are sets and N $\subseteq$ M and |N| = |M| and if there’s another set N’ with N $\subseteq$ N‘ $\subseteq$ M then |N‘| = |M|. Reminder: we interpret |N‘| = |M| as a bijective function f: N‘ $\to$ M, so we don‘t have cardinals or AC.

Any idea? The proof of CB while assuming the above theorem is easy for me to understand while the classical proof is somewhat confusing. But of course it would be great if I could also proof the above theorem and so be able to prove CB as a whole. Please note that I am not a mathematician, so please be as simple and explainative as you can.

Comment: That premise basically **is** Cantor-Bernstein; it's not any easier to prove.

Comment: Cr*p. No wonder it was so nice to prove CB with it. I guess I have to settle for it then. What do you think: if one tries a prove like CB but you cannot wrap your head around it after some hours, is it better to move on or to stay and try and try and try and try till you got it? I have no idea about math, but in life I often found that it is better to move forward instead of trying too hard (and lose interest). Whats your take?

Comment: Pippen, your question (the philosophy one not the CBT one) is a perennial favorite on this site; if you search "how to prove things" and the self-study tag you will find enough "takes" to drown in. (More specifically, of course you know CBT is a proof that requires a novel idea, by which I mean that it is in no way suggested by the problem statement; but equally obviously there's no way to know such things ahead of time.)